# How to make a contour plot from a .dat file

Tags: plotting

I have a .dat file (which is actually a csv), whose columns are like

```
x1 y1 z1 w1
x2 y2 z2 w2
x3 y3 z3 w3
.  .  .  .
.  .  .  .
```

I want to separately obtain contour plots of `z(x,y)` and `w(x,y)` from the set of data.

I have imported the file with

```
mydata = Import["filename.dat","CSV"];
```

Now I can form the vectors containing x, y, z values with

```
x = mydata[[All, 1]];
y = mydata[[All, 2]];
z = mydata[[All, 3]];
```

How to do the contour plot? The `ContourPlot` function works with a function, not points.

I don't necessarily need to interpolate between the points to make it a smooth function. If there is some way to plot densities at discrete points, that will also do. However, if there is a way to do this with interpolation, or if there is some inbuilt routine to achieve this, I am also interested to know about that.

The function `ListContourPlot` requires a `n x 3` matrix, but my data is `n x 4`. How can I select a column specifically?

Comment: [`ListContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListContourPlot.html)? See if `ListContourPlot[ mydata[[All, ;;3]] ]` and `ListContourPlot[ mydata[[All, {1, 2, 4}]] ]` do what you want.

Comment: Yes the second form wouldn’t work, because you are selecting the first four columns to pass to ListCountourPlot. Did you try the {1, 2, 4} syntax I showed you in my previous comment for your second case?

Comment: @MarcoB yes, the {1,2,4} syntax works. Please write it as an answer and I will accept it

Comment: Glad it worked. I’ve done that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ListContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListContourPlot.html) will do what you need. In particular:

```
ListContourPlot[ mydata[[All, ;;3]] ]
ListContourPlot[ mydata[[All, {1, 2, 4}]] ]
```

should do what you want.